# How to detect touch event on drawn item using drawRect method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, core-graphics

If i draw a circle using `drawRect` method of `UIView`, how to detect its touch or tap? I am  having multiple circles and also have to edit(change color, ...) the selected circle. Or I have to use some another approach for same. Does `CoreGraphics`, `OpenGL` any use in this case?

Comment: Did you tried `touchesBegan`?

Comment: how should i get that touched circle object, and redraw only that after editing?

Comment: Store circle's parameters like position of it's center (X and Y) and radius (R), then in toucesBegan and other touch methods perform calculations if touch's x and y match
(X-x)^2 + (Y-y)^2 <= R^2

Comment: Also you may just add a subview that will draw a circle on the whole frame and catch touches on added view

Comment: You can't use `drawRect:` to detect touch events. `drawRect:` is for drawing; nothing else. There are other methods for handling events.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer. We have to do this using `CGPath Hit Testing`. Check this [link](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/cgpath-hit-testing/).

Comment: Why not use `CGPathContainsPoint`? See [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000959-CH1g-CJBGIGEF) for API details.